# Split elements of a list with multiple columns into irregular weekly intervals in R

Tags: r, date, split, xts

This question is attached to a question asked earlier about splitting an xts object into irregular weekly intervals, [Split xts object by specified irregular intervals in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491490/split-xts-object-by-specified-irregular-intervals-in-r/31491831?noredirect=1#comment51065080_31491831)
- however with the addition of a list containing xts objects which has multiple columns.

Instead of one daily xts object, I have managed to split the daily series into monthly elements (with daily data), hence for a period of 2 years, I would have a list of 24 xts elements which contain daily data.

example:

```
week <- seq(from=as.Date("2004-01-01"), to=as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day")
x2 <- sample(1:1000, 731, replace = FALSE)
x3 <- sample(1:1000, 731, replace = FALSE)
x4 <- sample(1:1000, 731, replace = FALSE)
var1 <- xts(x2, order.by = week)
var2 <- xts(x3, order.by = week)
var3 <- xts(x4, order.by = week)
daily.series <- merge.xts(var1, var2, var3)
split_monthly <- split(daily.series, f = "months", k = 1)
```

What I want to do is split the the elements in the split_monthly list into irregular intervals as had been done in the link above.

Initially this worked:

```
for (i in seq_along(split_monthly)){
intervals <- cut(.indexmday(split_monthly[[i]]$var1), c(0, 7, 14, 21, 31), paste0("W", 1:4))
splitlist[[i]] <- split(split_monthly[[i]], intervals)
splitlist}
```

But I would like to run it through each column i.e. `var1, var2, var3` in a *for loop* (which is what I prefer).

I've been stuck on this issue for the past 2 days, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example doesn't run - what's `split_list`?

Comment: No, it still doesn't run. Try copy-paste your "reproducible" example into a clean console after `library(xts)` - errors. You are using `split_monthly[[1]]$unemployed` but there is no unemployed column. And do you really want to be using `split_monthly[[1]]` or `split_monthly[[i]]`? What is your desired output?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: How about now? I've edit the issues...it runs smoothly on my side. 
The desired output is splitlist[[i]] for i (so for each column) - this is where I can't catch a break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what your desired output is, but you could simply do (e.g.)

```
lapply(splitlist[[1]], '[', j='var1')
```

And this will give you the values of `var1` in the first month split up by week, and so on?

```
$W1
2004-01-01 2004-01-02 2004-01-03 2004-01-04 2004-01-05 2004-01-06 2004-01-07 
       281        518        630        301        194        480        952 

$W2
2004-01-08 2004-01-09 2004-01-10 2004-01-11 2004-01-12 2004-01-13 2004-01-14 
       335        371        668        138        680        631         68 

$W3
2004-01-15 2004-01-16 2004-01-17 2004-01-18 2004-01-19 2004-01-20 2004-01-21 
       975        424        142        212         35        718        534 

$W4
2004-01-22 2004-01-23 2004-01-24 2004-01-25 2004-01-26 2004-01-27 2004-01-28 2004-01-29 2004-01-30 2004-01-31 
       359        805        320        628        219        373        641        812        617        606
```

Or you could just do a loop along your variables if you require an explicit for loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(split_monthly)){
    intervals <- cut(.indexmday(split_monthly[[i]]$var1), c(0, 7, 14, 21, 31), paste0("W", 1:4))

    for (var in names(split_monthly[[i]])) {
        split(split_monthly[[i]][, var], intervals)
        # do some processing here
    }
}
```

Again, not entirely clear what you are after. You could swap the `var` and `i` loop if your processing needs to occur by `var` before by `month`?

Comment: Could I not specify it by the number of columns also? something like
`for (j in 1:ncol(split_monthly[[i]])) {`
???

Comment: Sure. whatever suits you.

Comment: You need to be much more specific as to what your desired output is. This is why the both of us who have answered do not seem to have answers matching what you want - it is very unclear what you want. Clarify your question and we will clarify our answers. I don't nkow what "It doesn't seem to work" means - is there an error? what "output" are you after?

Answer (score 0):

Is this along the lines of what you wanted? I'm still not sure exactly what you're asking for:

```
week <- seq(from=as.Date("2004-01-01"), to=as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day")
x2 <- sample(1:1000, 731, replace = FALSE)
x3 <- sample(1:1000, 731, replace = FALSE)
x4 <- sample(1:1000, 731, replace = FALSE)
var1 <- xts(x2, order.by = week)
var2 <- xts(x3, order.by = week)
var3 <- xts(x4, order.by = week)

for(v in 1:3){
    daily.series <- get(paste0('var',v))
    intervals_day <- cut(.indexmday(daily.series), c(0, 7, 14, 21, 31), paste0("W", 1:4))
    intervals_month <- cut(.indexmon(daily.series),12, paste0("M", 1:12))
    intervals_year <- cut(.indexyear(daily.series),2, paste0("Y", 1:2))
    intervals <- as.factor(paste(intervals_year,intervals_month,intervals_day))
    assign(paste0('split_monthly_var',v),split(daily.series, intervals))
}
```

EDIT: added intervals_year above

Just to check, this one seems ok:

```
split_monthly_var1[[1]]
```

This one is not ok, `.indexmon()` seems to be messing up, but that could be solved if I'm on the right track.

```
split_monthly_var1[[48]]
```

EDIT:
to circumvent the `.indexmon()` issue you could extract the dates as a character and split the string to extract just the month:

```
for(v in 1:3){
    daily.series <- get(paste0('var',v))
    intervals_day <- cut(.indexmday(daily.series), c(0, 7, 14, 21, 31), paste0("W", 1:4))
    dates_list <- strsplit(as.character(as.Date(.indexDate(daily.series))),"-")
    intervals_month <- paste0('M',lapply(dates_list,'[',2))
    intervals_year <- cut(.indexyear(daily.series),2, paste0("Y", 1:2))
    intervals <- as.factor(paste(intervals_year,intervals_month,intervals_day))
    assign(paste0('split_monthly_var',v),split(daily.series, intervals))
}
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this approach is that the elements are grouped for every two years so you end up with 2004-01-01:2004-07-01 & 2005-01-01:2005-01-07.
What if each week were an element within a list  on it's own?